# Should I be using @ or ~ in JS imports (Vue.js/Nuxt.js)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find the appropriate answer to my question.

As you might know, Webpack has an alias for the root dir which is `~`. That said, I have seen many people use the `@` symbol when importing modules using ES6 syntax. Both works when importing modules.

My question is this... Is there any consequences by using the `~` symbol when importing modules in pages and components or is it just a best practise to be using `@`? I use `~` since there is less chance for me to mix up the two since the `nuxt.config.js` file does not support the use of `@`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way of referencing a `root` folder in JS. From my knowledge this is not specified in any specs.

Both `~` and `@` are defined by whatever package bundler your using.

In this case going with whatever is standard for that environment should be fine.

I'm more used with `@` because that's the default for vue.js/webpack installs, but I would use anything that comes out of the box with a different setup.

Comment: Thanks for your insight :)

Answer (score 1):

The `~`-prefix is used to resolve the import from the `node_modules`-path.
The `@`-prefix is set-up in Vue to resolve the import from the `src`-path.

Comment: But then why does my imports work in vue.js/nuxt.js when my components I'm importing is not in the `node_modules` folder? And this still does not answer my original question though. Should I continue to use `~`?